# Entity Framewok. Add a new record and return total records by only one query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and I have a method which adds an object to the user favorites. I need to add an object and then return total addings of this element in the all users favorites:

```
public class FavoritesRepository : BaseRepository
{
     public async Task<Favorites> AddAsync(Favorites favorites)
     {
       _context.Add(favorites);
       await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

       return favorites;
    }
}


public class FavoritesService
{
   public async Task<AddFavoritesElementOperationResultModel> AddAsync(ObjectType objectType, long objectId)
   {
      //Some business logic
      favorites = new Favorites
      {
         ObjectTypeId = objectTypeId,
         ObjectId = objectId,
         AuthorUserId = currentUserId
       };
       favorites = await _favoritesRepository.AddAsync(favorites);

       long total = await _favoritesRepository.GetFavoritesElementCountAsync(objectTypeId, objectId);
       return new AddFavoritesElementOperationResultModel
       {
          Id = favorites.Id,
          ObjectTypeId = objectTypeId,
          ObjectId = objectId,
          Total = total
       };
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add and return the total count of addings of this element by only one query at insert, i.e. without calling GetFavoritesElementCountAsync(..)?

Comment: Maybe use sp that would save data and return count. But I'm affraid there would be a little gain: finally db would do two things: adding new row and counting all rows. If you have many writers then reading total count can be blocking.

Comment: You want to return the number added? The SaveChanges method returns the number of rows affected.

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell, no, I want to return total specified records after adding. For example, the table Favorites contains 10 records about a post with id = 10 (and 600 total records, for example) and I'm adding a new one. I need to return 11 in this case, i.e. select count(*) from Favorites where post_id = 10. I need to know, how many times this post was added in user favorites